# Como fazer um "Hello Word!" dessa forma

Tags: javascript, estrutura-de-dados, funções

Sem utilizar os itens abaixo:

1. Strings e funções do tipo String antes da saída
2. Números
3. Expressões Regulares
4. Funções com os nomes:  "Hello", "World", "HelloWorld" ou qualquer coisa similar somente o método de saída `var helloWord = function(){ //aqui seu código }`.
5. Sem usar chaves de objetos com nomes: "Hello", "World", "HelloWorld" ou qualquer coisa similar.

Eu cheguei a fazer o exemplo abaixo, mas o problema identificou que estou usando string, alguém tem uma outra ideia?

**http://jsfiddle.net/ivanferrer/qv2xtvcv/**

Comment: excelente desafio, qual o objetivo, puramente acadêmico?

Comment: E guardar em um array cada caractere? Em uma posição vai H, em outra E e assim por diante. É valido?

Comment: Achei isso, http://jsfiddle.net/E4b5d/1/ , bem loco oO.

Comment: @henriquedpereira, é legal, porém tem string no neste método.

Comment: @GiancarloGiulian essa ideia não rola, pois array tem chave numérica, já tentamos isso, usando range.

Comment: @h3nr1ke esse desafio foi proposto em uma das etapas desse site: http://www.codewars.com/ e não estou conseguindo pensar em como poderia resolver de outra forma.

Comment: Obrigado pelo comentário @IvanFerrer

Comment: Aqui tem uma saída que possibilitou resolver o problema: http://www.jsfuck.com/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontrei a solução:

```
var helloWorld = function () {
  // Hello World!
  var start = [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,].length,
      end = [,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,].length;
  alert(helloWorld.toString().slice(start, end));
}
helloWorld();
```

Comment: Funções com os nomes: "Hello", "World", "HelloWorld" ou qualquer coisa similar.

Comment: Mas a função pode ser: `hel = function() { ... }`, o importante é não usar o nome da função como resultado, como disse, somente método de saída.

Answer (score 2):

tente fazer o seguinte:

```js
function SGVsbG8gV29scmQh() { }
var helloWolrd = function () {
  alert(atob(new SGVsbG8gV29scmQh().constructor.name));
}
helloWolrd();
```

Comment: Legal, só que você escreveu a palavra World errado e o método principal é persistente, tem que ser `helloWorld()`!

Comment: @IvanFerrer, corrigido.

Comment: A palavra continua errada, @TobyMosque, vc inverteu o "r" e o "l"